# Tracking Checkout Behavior with a data layer and Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have a single page checkout and would like to track each step in the report E-Commerce > Checkout Behaviour.

Currently this report looks like this for me:

[image]

The problem is, that only the first step gets tracked, but never the following steps.

I have however checked, using multiple plugins, that data for other steps are being pushed to the data layer.

For example, here we can clearly see, that other steps are being included in the beacons:

[image]

However, I only ever see the first step in Google Analytics.

The only difference between the first steps and all other steps seems to be, that the first step is executed on page load, whereas the subsequent steps are executed on user actions (clicks) on the same page.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I get this to work?

I also have a GTM Event, which looks like this:
[image]

The web site for reference is: https://www.zeolith-bentonit-versand.de/de/zeolith.html

Comment: I can only guess but I think either your trigger is not setup correctly since you are pushing data to dataLayer. (Can you post screenshot of checkOption trigger?) Or your tag is setup to fire only once per page. You can check this by going to your Tag > Advanced Settings > Tag Firing Options

Comment: I added a screen shot. The tag is set to "once per event". Might this be a problem? Ill try with unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

I cant get to your site from the network I am currently on, but it looks like your event hits tracking your checkout steps are not correctly configured to use the eCommerce module.

Take a close look at this section of Google'd documentation:
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#checkoutstep

IF the data getting pushed into the datalayer during this step is correctly formatted, it may be as simple as flagging the event that is firing here to use ecommerce:
Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true

You will know if you have it right when you see ecommerce parameters in the tracking hit, in this case specifically &COL and &COS parameters.
See here for a reference of what you should see
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cos

what would be helpful is to post the contents of you data layer right before the hit you showed above is sent.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that you are only trying to track a checkout option for further steps, and not the checkout step itself. This is the reason, why the step is not visible in your reports.

If you look at the payload on the screenshot about the debugger, your `ec:action` (&pa=) is checkout_option. Based on the [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#checkout_option) (emphasis by me):

> The checkout option is useful in cases where **you've already measured a
>   checkout step** but you want to capture additional information about the
>   same checkout step. For example, the shipping method selected by a
>   user.

So I suggest to change the dataLayer used for these steps to contain all the necessary data (products checked out), and to adjust the ecommerce action to `checkout`. Further details are available [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#checkoutstep), although your call about first step seems to be working, so that can be a reference as well.